# Playing audio from OS X launchd daemon

Tags: macos, audio, applescript, launchd, launch-daemon

I am trying to execute an Apple Script from my launchd daemon. My script has just one line and it is given below.

```
say "Message From Daemon!"
```

This always fails and throws this error message "File some object wasn't found".

Any idea why this is happening? The same script works properly if I run from xcode (not launching it via launchd) and from any other app that runs in user context.

Comment: A daemon can't display UI messages and I wouldn't be surprised if it can't output audio either. Check the Console logs to see if there are any clues there.

Comment: I am guessing the same. But I am not able to find anything in the console logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing sound using `NSSound` rely on the `window server` and daemon is not allowed to connect to the window server.

I am assuming same issue with `say` command. ( This tool uses the **Speech Synthesis manager** to convert input text to audible speech and either play it through the sound output device chosen in System
       Preferences or save it to an AIFF file.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're running into the same problem I had originally when I tried the same kind of thing. The path in your .plist file needs to point deeper into the applescript application. Below is an example of the .plist file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.namespace.script_name</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/Applications/script_name.app/Contents/MacOS/applet</string>
        <key>LowPriorityIO</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Nice</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>7200</integer>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: My daemon is not an apple script. I am running an apple script from my daemon using NSAppleScript -> executeAndReturnError method.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood